# How to show that limit of $(x^3+y^3)/(x-y)$ does not exist at origin?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> Show that the limit as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ does not exist for the function
>   $$
> f(x,t)=\begin{cases}\frac{x^3+y^3}{x-y},\quad & x\ne y \\ 0,\quad & x=y\end{cases}
> $$

My solution is below, but it appears to be inconsistent with the problem. What is wrong?

[image]

[image]

Comment: PLEASE AVOID ASKING QUESTIONS ALL IN CAPS !

Comment: Is this reason for downvoting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conversion to polar coordinates does not prove the limit exists, because in doing so, you are assuming that as $r \to 0^+$, that $\theta$ is a fixed constant with respect to the change in $r$, thus you are only considering a subset of all possible paths tending toward $(0,0)$--specifically, the subset of all **straight-line paths** to the origin.

See this post for a similar problem, and more information: [Limit is found using polar coordinates but it is not supposed to exist.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753381/limit-is-found-using-polar-coordinates-but-it-is-not-supposed-to-exist/753389#753389)

So, the prove that the limit does not exist, it suffices to discover two distinct paths to $(0,0)$, each suitably parametrized, such that the limit along these paths are unequal to each other.

Comment: that similar question helped me a lot thanks

Comment: @godonichia Can you help me, with the solution of the problem? What paths did you considered?