# Why cannot we say The limit $\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{x y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{4}}=0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates

I used Polar coordinates to evaluate $$L=\lim _{(x, y) \rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{x y^{2}}{x^{2}+y^{4}}$$

We have $x=r\cos \theta$ and $y=r\sin \theta$ and as $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ we have $r \to 0$
So we get
$$L=\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r\cos \theta \sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}=0$$

So irrespective of any path, the limit is zero. I know that this is wrong since the limit actually does not exist, But i have seen some threads in this forum. Here is what i understood.

Even though $r \to 0$, the quantity $$f(r, \theta)=\frac{ \cos \theta \sin ^{2} \theta}{\cos ^{2} \theta+r^{2} \sin ^{4} \theta}$$ might be infinity for some of the paths other than the straight line. For example if we choose the path $x=y^2$, then when $r \to 0$ we get $\theta \to \frac{\pi}{2}$. So the quantity $\frac{\cos \theta \sin ^{2} \theta}{\cos ^{2} \theta+r^{2} \sin ^{4} \theta}$ blows up to infinity. So the limit Does not exist. Is this the correct analysis? Any inputs please add.

Comment: $r \rightarrow 0$ need not imply $\theta \rightarrow \pi/2$ if you're restricting your point of view to the curve $x=y^2$. You should say $\theta \rightarrow \pm \pi/2$ as $r \rightarrow 0$

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3334502/conditions-to-exploit-polar-coordinates-in-limits/

Answer (score 2):

This claim:

$$L=\lim_{r \to 0}\frac{r\cos \theta \sin^2\theta}{\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta}=0$$

is not justified. Perhaps we follow a path where $\theta$ is a function of $r$, and it's just not clear that the limit will be $0$. In fact as you found, for some paths the limit is not $0$.

Comment: The way that the first part of the question reads to me is that the OP intended $\theta$ to be be taken as a constant.  This, of course, should be made much clearer and explicit.

Comment: I don't see the suggestion that $\theta$ should be constant, unless that is a mistaken position on the part of the OP. As $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ in the original limit, there isn't a requirement for $\theta$ to be constant. OP seems to acknowledge this by considering a path like $x=y^2$, where $\theta$ is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis looks to be mostly correct (although it could be clearer and more precise) that the limit doesn't exist, but there isn't a need to introduce $\sin$ and $\cos$.  Following the path $x=y^2$ means that you need to compute the limit:
$$
\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{y^2y^2}{(y^2)^2+y^4}=\lim_{y\rightarrow 0}\frac{2y^4}{y^4}=2.
$$