# Troubles understanding when certain quantity is bounded :

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to study the following function :
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)\\ 0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \end{cases}$$
I started by showing it's continuous at $(0,0)$ :

\begin{align*}
\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} f(x,y) &= \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^4}\\
&= \lim_{r\to 0 } r^2 \dfrac{\cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta}{\cos^2 \theta + r^2 \sin^4\theta}\\
&= 0
\end{align*}
It's $0$ because the $r^2 \sin^4\theta\to 0$ so as the whole expression, and I checked my answer using Wolfram alpha and it is true.

Well when it comes to check if the function is $\mathcal{C}^1$, I must prove that the partial derivatives exist and they're continuous :
$$\partial_x f(0,0) = \lim_{x\to 0 } \dfrac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x}=0$$
But :
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \partial_x f(x,y) = \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{2xy^6}{(x^2+y^4)^2} $$
Its limit doesn't exist as Wolfram Alpha says, because :
$$\dfrac{2r^5\cos\theta \sin^6\theta}{(\cos^2\theta+r^2\sin^4\theta)^2}$$
Isn't bounded, but according to my philosophy that I used to solve the continuity it is since $r^2\sin^4 \theta\to 0$ and the limit as well.

Any help to overcome this confusion ?

Comment: Very similar to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/753381/limit-fracx2yx4y2-is-found-using-polar-coordinates-but-it-is-not-supp?rq=1

Comment: In the last expression there should be $r^3$ in the numerator

Answer (score 2):

What if $\cos ^{2}\theta$ also tends to $0$? In that case the denominator tends to $0$.

Along $x=y^{2} $ the limit is $\frac 1 2 $ and the limit along the coordinate axes is $0$. So the limit does not exist.